# Where do I put processing that needs to be done before onCreate()?

Tags: android

My application needs to read a file and process that information to build the list need by the activity.  I can't find a good place to do it.  What I have is in the body of the activity, in a { do the work } block.  If I don't put the {...} around it, there are errors.  This works, but is it the 'correct' way to do this? Is there a better way? This processing is only done once.
Thanks for your help

Cliff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It kind of depends on what exactly you are doing, but one common way to do lengthy processing is to create a subclass of [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) that does the processing in its `doInBackground` method and updates the UI in its `onPostExecute` method. Then, you can create an instance of the AsyncTask in `onCreate` or `onResume`, call its `execute` method, and still have a responsive UI while the processing is occurring.

That's the way I would do it if the processing is tied to that particular Activity, such that you might want to stop the processing if the user left the Activity. If the processing were more generally useful and generated data that might be used elsewhere in the app, then I'd consider using a subclass of [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) or [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).

Specifics are always helpful. If you can share more details about what you are trying to do, it will be easier to suggest the most appropriate solution.

Comment: The file contains information about books (author,title,publisher,pages,category,...) The actual data is determined by the user when they select what they want to see in the mobile version. I read in the data and put it in a 'String[][]'.  Once I have read the files, I make a singleton object that just holds the data and set the String[][]=null.  Then I make and sort the list for a list view.  Now I can create the listView for the UI.

Comment: I have been reading the link you provided(AsyncTask).  That looks like what I have been looking for.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Seconded, you want to start an asynctask in onCreate(), set everything up (except the adapter), and update the adapter/listview in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Thanks for the hints.  I have run into a couple of problems. One is, I am new to Java and I can not find any reference to (type... in).  I think this is a variable argument of type 'type', but I can't find any references for it.

Comment: Yes, that is the syntax for a variable arity method. Another thing you should look out for is the AsyncTask instance getting destroyed and recreated on a configuration change (e.g., a rotation of the device). To avoid that, you can make it a static member of your class or save it in `onSaveInstanceState` and pull it back out of the Bundle passed in via `onCreate(Bundle)`.

Comment: Again, thanks for the hints.  For some reason I am having trouble reading the file.  I worked fine in a java only environment. I have added a cancel in the onDestory() method.  I will follow your advice above when I fix the file problem.

Comment: Is there anyway I can 'startActivity(myInt);' in 'onPostExecute()'?

Comment: Yes, you can start a new Activity from `onPostExecute` by creating an Intent and passing it to `startActivity`

Comment: OK you can do it with 'parent.startActivity(myInt);' @Brian Cooley

Answer (score 0):

You can see the Android Activity lifecycle here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

As you can see, `onCreate()` is the first thing that happens when an `Activity` is launched. Depending on the size of your file, it's OK to read it in the `onCreate()` method. Alternatively, you can set up your layout and then create a `ProgressDialog` that shows the file loading - once it's done loading, you just dispose the dialog and build the list you want.

Comment: It is a big file.  The stuff that is in the body actually gets done before  onCreate().  I don't want to hangup onCreate() while its being done, but maybe that's the best way.  Just looking for some alternatives.  Thanks for your reply.